# How do I set my profile's title in StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

I can't find a way to change my profile's title in any way. I tried looking both in game and also online in my Battle.net account settings.

I have a Legacy of the Void key activated and using the latest patch of the game of course.

Please check the image below for a player that has their title properly set (highlighted in a red box). I've blurred their character's name to protect their privacy.

[image: Player profile example with title highlighted inside red box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm considered, this "title" you're referring to is the name of the clan you've joined. At least this is what my profile's giving me. If you'd like to change what it says, consider creating a clan - or join an existing one.